# Saving time in SVN post-commit hooks?

Tags: svn, version-control, hook, post-commit, svn-hooks

At my place of work we've started to introduce proper SVN hooks, "proper" meaning "doing a lot of policy checking". Currently, our policy consists of Perl::Critic with Perl::Tidy checking enabled. However, especially the latter one takes a lot of time on commits with several to many files touched and SVN wouldn't return until the post-commit hook is done.

Is there any way I can save some time in the post-commit hook without sacrificing policy checks?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need some report (like list of errors) then you can use [Continious Intergation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system run some post commit actions. This systems allow to put any action after changes in your source control system made. Here is example scenario:

- Some one commit to SVN repository
- After some time CC founds this change and runs the script:

  - Get latest version from SVN
  - Run checks like Perl::Critic and Perl::Tidy
- If any check failed then

  - Create detailed error report (which is available from web)
  - Send email notification if necessary

There are many good Continious Intergation system. I like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

Answer (score 2):

This is another place where branch-based development can be useful.  Essentially you create a new branch for each task you want to do.  The branch is exempt from the quality checks, but the merge to `trunk` or whatever is not.  So your day-to-day commits are fast, and it's only slow to merge.  And you can reduce the pain of that by putting together a bot to do that task for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the commit to fail if the hook says "no", the commit has to wait for the hook to finish its check.

Besides speeding up the check, I can't see anything you can do. (Except for the old mantra: commit often. Then you won't commit so many files at once.)